# How do I debug Drupal\Component\PhpStorage\FileStorage::createDirectory()?

Tags: files, 9, debugging

On my site, I am getting this warning.

> Alert: User warning: mkdir(): Permission Denied in Drupal\Component\PhpStorage\FileStorage->createDirectory() (line 123 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/PhpStorage/FileStorage.php).

I want to debug or get the exact path and directory where Drupal is trying to create the directory.

I tried changing the file permissions for sites/default/files with `chmod -R 777` path, without success.

How can I debug it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because debugging is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The standard debugger for PHP is [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org). Install it and set a breakpoint at that line. If for some reason you cannot use Xdebug, `\Drupal::logger('my_module')->notice($message)` or `error_log()` the filename to be written and examine the logs.

Comment: My Problem is at server. I can't debug at server.

Comment: Error showing in core files i can't update core file.

Comment: @KamalOberoi If you can’t use a debugger and you can’t edit the files, how do you expect to debug the site?

Comment: @Clive I want to use debugger but error is showing at core files. I don't want to put drupal logger in core files. If i know error is coming from my custom module or any contrib module then i can put try / catch and logger.

Comment: I vote to close this question as unanswerable. I provided a correct answer detailing how to debug in Drupal but the constraint is that no debugging is possible.