# mkdir(): Permission Denied in core/lib/Drupal/Component/PhpStorage/FileStorage.php

Tags: 10

On every site page, I am getting these errors:

```
User warning: mkdir(): Permission Denied in Drupal\Component\PhpStorage\FileStorage->createDirectory() (line 123 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/PhpStorage/FileStorage.php).
Drupal\Component\PhpStorage\FileStorage->createDirectory('sites/default/files/php/twig', 509) (Line: 73)

Drupal\Component\PhpStorage\FileStorage->ensureDirectory('sites/default/files/php/twig') (Line: 66)
Drupal\Component\PhpStorage\MTimeProtectedFastFileStorage->save('65cd8eafb5bac_status-messages.html.twig_GfCMeKK44m7xVsgW6vKS2K1IN', '&lt;?php

[followed by contents of a twig php file it looks like]
```

I am also getting the same or very similar errors when I try to clear caches from the site but not if I use `drush cr` on the cli.

My sites/default/files directory has 777 permissions and is owned by the webserver (apache).

I did see this issue which seems very similar but I can't add any comments there. [How do I debug Drupal\Component\PhpStorage\FileStorage::createDirectory()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/310911/how-do-i-debug-drupal-component-phpstorage-filestoragecreatedirectory)

I would be happy to try using the `\Drupal::logger('my_module')->notice($message)` but can you tell me where to put that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to reproduce this error by changing the ownership/permission of sites/default/files/php, so that the web server no longer can access it, and clearing the content of the directory (this is only a cache and can be cleared without data loss). The next site visit will create a ton of these warnings.

Since you have full error reporting already enabled, you see all debugging details and don't need the linked topic.

What you need to do is to set up Drupal according to web/core/INSTALL.txt. If this is not a new install, this depends on the steps you did before to cause the error. If, for example, you have migrated the site to a different host, you might need to adjust the directories/files ownership and permissions. See this great tutorial https://www.singlemindconsulting.com/blog/fixing-permissions-on-the-files-directory-in-drupal/

Comment: Thanks. Good to know that I don't need more debugging messages. I went through the tutorial you linked, but my permissions were already set as it recommends. (And I'm still getting the errors.)

Comment: OK, the docs I've mentioned are for traditional Unix systems. If you use something else you have to adapt the commands, but the concept of the Drupal file system still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the reason for the permissions errors in my case is SELinux not allowing the Apache httpd process to write to the filesystem. The fix is:

```
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /path/to/sites/default/files/
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50639/httpd-cant-write-to-folder-file-because-of-selinux